# Moving Away From Feedburner Mybrand

Tags: .htaccess, rss, subdomain, feedburner

With recent changes announced for Feedburner, I want to move my RSS feed from using Feedburner. As I have been using its [MyBrand feature](https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/79586#) where you can brand the Feedburner with your own domain name, I now need to setup the redirect to "move" it back.

I host with a shared host and can create an .htaccess file, and I have tried rewrite rules using a test subdomain and I haven't been able to get it to work, and am thus asking for assistance.

The Feedburner URL is structured as follows:

http://feeds.example.com/example

and it "redirects" to a URL structured as follows:

https://www.example.com/index.php/site/rss_2.0/

I created a CNAME to test this of "feedstest" to try it without playing with the live RSS feed and I couldn't get it to work.

THANKS!

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far and how that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi - I created a subdomain "testfeed" as a CNAME, and tried various rewrite rules. As none of them worked, I never saved them.

Comment: I can’t even clearly tell, from what you want to redirect to where here. _“and it "redirects" to a URL structured as follows”_ - that’s what is already happening? Or what you need?

Comment: It is currently redirecting this way, but thru Feedburner. The subdomain FEEDS is pointing to Feedburner. So I am trying to do this myself, both point the subdomain to my own site, and do the rewrite rule there.